# document.forms[1] submits document.forms[0]. Why?

Tags: javascript

```js
function newcheckform() { 
   if(document.forms[0].term1.value == "") { 
     alert("Field cannot be empty!");
     return false;
   } else document.forms[1].submit();
 }


 window.onload = function() { 
  document.getElementById("form-button1").onclick = newcheckform;

}
```

```html
<form action="firstform.php" id="firstform">
  <input type="search" name="term1" id="termid1" placeholder="first form">
  <button id="form-button1">Submit1</button>
</form>


<form action="secondform.php" id="secondform">
  <input type="search" name="term2" id="termid2" placeholder="second form">
  <button id="form-button2">Submit2</button>
</form>
```

When the `submit button` is clicked, the function checks if the input of the `firstform` is empty, and if no, then it should submit `forms[1]`, which is `secondform`, yet the `firstform` is being submitted. Why?

Same thing does not happen if you manually use the `form` attribute on the first button to target the `secondform`.

Could it be because since the button is inside the form, when I click it, the form gets submitted faster than it takes for the script to submit the `secondform`. I am not sure if that makes much sense.

Comment: Please may you never use `onclick` to submit forms? [The Enter Key should Submit Forms, Stop Suppressing it](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/01/01/enter-should-submit-forms-stop-messing-with-that/)

Comment: @definitelynotme A button in a form will naturally cause the form to submit. form1 is being submitted by your button and not by ur JS. You can return `false` to disable the submission of form1, or change your button to be of `type="button"` so it doesn't submit the form (then there would be no need to return false)

Comment: So you're saying that, the form is submitted before the last part of the function gets executed? I just tested this using `type=button` instead, which does not normally submit a form, and it works this time, which reinforces the idea that the form gets submitted before `document.forms[2].submit()` gets executed.

Comment: @NickParsons Sorry, quick question. How would you propose returning false to simultaneously disable the button so the first form doesn't get submitted, and at the same time, trigger the submission of the second form? Obviously it can be done by nesting or referencing other functions, but is there an easier way?

Comment: @definitelynotme If I understand correctly, removing the `return false` from your function and just using `type="button"` on your button in form1 should do the trick. That way, when you click on the submit button for form1, form1 won't naturally submit, so you can pass all submission control to the function. The function is then responsible for submitting form2, or alerting the user if a value isn't set.

Comment: Also, I am just reading the MDN explanation, and does anyone have any idea what do they mean by this sentence `<input> with attribute type="submit" will not be submitted with the form when using HTMLFormElement.submit(), but it would be submitted when you do it with original HTML form submit.`?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit How is `type=submit` not being submitted with the `submit()` method?

Comment: @NickParsons Yeah but the issue then is that, even when empty, it will still get submitted.  If I remove the `return false` if empty, there's nothing preventing the submission of an empty field.

Comment: @definitelynotme nothing should be submitting the form if you set the button to be `type="button"`. If the field is empty, the form won't submit, since nothing is making it submit, so you don't need to prevent it from submitting. Eg: https://jsfiddle.net/cmrzutod/

Comment: @NickParsons I think you misunderstand what I want to do. The idea is that when you press the button, the `secondform` should get submitted. If the first field is empty, and I remove the `return false`, the `secondform` will get submitted even if the first one is empty.

Comment: _"What's the problem with using onclick to submit a form?"_ please may you read the article I linked?

Comment: @NickParsons Never mind about that. There isn't a way of doing it without using another function for reference. Can you help me out with the statement from the MDN website above?

Comment: @NickParsons Oh, I get what you mean now. It took me a while to process. Yep, you're right. You don't need the `return false` since if it's empty, just the alert will be triggered and nothing will get submitted.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Can you help me understand what do MDN mean by that sentence I cited above?

Comment: Inputs usually have values that are sent on submit. If they have a type of "submit" then the value they have is not sent.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I thought so too, and I tested it, and it really does not get submitted, but the `value` attribute also don't get submitted even if I use `type=button`? What is the `original HTML form submit`? I thought the original was `type=submit`?

Comment: the default input type is `text`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I think I understand now. When using `type=submit`, the `name` and `value` will get submitted too, but if you use `type=button` or just `<button>` they will not be submitted.

Comment: Actually it still doesn't work. I am getting a bit irritated. MDN says that if you submit a form using `type=submit` WITH the `submit()` JS method, then the `name` and `value` of the `input` button will not be submitted. However, if you do it without the `submit()` method, then it will be submitted. Well, I tested this, and it only works if I use `submit()` without using an event handler to trigger it, if I do, then it doesn't work, the `value` and `name` both get submitted. I am completely lost. This is why I dislike MDN.

Comment: I am going to have to conclude that what MDN says is not true unless somebody can explain to me why using `type=submit` submits the `name` and `value` regardless if I use JS `submit()` or not.

Comment: MDN is correct though? https://11bxm.csb.app/ if the input inside the form is cilcked, the input value is submitted. Using the submit method, the input value is not. (https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-hermann-11bxm)

Comment: You're right, but it's a bit misleading. This only works if you separate the event handler from the submit button inside the button. If you attach the event handler to the button that is linked to the form, then it doesn't work even if the button is outside the form. It only works if you use a button to trigger a function that submits the form.

Comment: I do not believe it is misleading. You're attaching a submit method to an input which already submits the form. The example I gave separates the two.

Comment: If you put a input `type=submit` inside a form, and click it, the `name` and `value` will get submitted despite the MDN saying that they will not. It's only if you create another button outside the form, and not link it with `form` to the `form id`, and then use that button to trigger a function `document.forms[0].submit()` only then it gets submitted without the `name` and `value`.

Comment: MDN doesn't say that. It says that if `.submit()` is used then the input name/value, which has a type of submit, will not be submitted. This is correct. When it says _"but it would be submitted when you do it with original HTML form submit"_ it's meaning clicking the input (which submits the form without JS).

Comment: Yeah, I misquoted it, but still, how can you submit it using `submit()`? Since if you try doing that, the form will get submitted from clicking the button and not by executing the `submit()` statement.

Comment: Clicking the button naturally submits the form, even if it triggers a function that uses `submit()`, the clicking will take precedence.

Comment: `() =>` what is this mean? I haven't studied this yet.

Comment: That is an arrow function. Similar to `function () {}`, but it has differences around how it handles `this`.

Comment: To submit a form using `submit` use something which doesn’t automatically submit the form without JavaScript. Like using a button with a type “button”. My preference is to listen to the native submit event, prevent it, do checks, and then fire `submit()` if everything is ok

Comment: Actually your code is not correct, because you are targeting `<button>` to submit the form, but MDN says using `input type=submit` will not submit it using `submit()` method, but you are not using `type=submit`, you are using `<button>`.

Comment: Yeah, I know that using `<button>` or `type=button` will not submit the `value` and `name`, but my point is that, MDN says using `type=submit` with `submit()` method will not submit it. It really doesn't, but only if you separate the event handler that triggers the `submit()` method from the `input type=submit` button inside the form.